# mysqldump single table from python subprocess

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess

I'm trying to dump a single table via mysqldump from within my python script running on Ubuntu.

```
args = ["mysqldump", f"-u{DBUser}", f"-h{DBHost}", f"-p{DBPass}", "--no-tablespaces", f'{DatabaseName}', f'{ArchiveTable}', '>', f'{BucketReadyName}']


subproc_output = subprocess.run(args)
```

This code gives this error.

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"
```

I've tried a couple different arrangements, but mysqldump always expects another table name rather than the end of the table list.

What do I need to do differently?  Is this a character escaping issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` is not a command argument, it's part of shell syntax. Since you're not using `shell=True` when calling `subprocess.run()`, it won't work.

Instead of using shell redirection, you can use the `stdout` argument to `subprocess.run()` to redirect to a file.

```
args = ["mysqldump", f"-u{DBUser}", f"-h{DBHost}", f"-p{DBPass}", "--no-tablespaces", f'{DatabaseName}', f'{ArchiveTable}']

with open(BucketReadyName, 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.run(args, stdout=outfile)
```