# execute awk (which redirects output to file) from python

Tags: python, bash, awk

Following awk command append file name to each line of log file

`awk '{print FILENAME  " "   $0}' progress.log > progress_temp.log`

How to execute this awk command from python

Able to execute the following command
`subprocess.run(["awk", "{print FILENAME \" \" $0}", "progress.log"])`
But it wont redirect output to progress_temp.log and don't want to handle that part in python.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790858/mysqldump-single-table-from-python-subprocess/66790898#66790898 for how easy it is to do the redirection from Python. Why don't you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, it's probably easiest to just use `os.system`:

```
import os

status = os.system("awk '{print FILENAME  \" \"   $0}' progress.log > progress_temp.log")
```

That way the shell will parse the command and handle the redirection for you.  The return value is the exit status (on Unix)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `stdout` argument to save the output into a specific file:

```
import subprocess
with open('progress_temp.log', 'w') as fw:
    subprocess.run(["awk", "{print FILENAME \" \" $0}", "progress.log"], stdout=fw)
```

Comment: @TomKarzes Now, it won't.